# How to list open ports and application using them in windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have trouble identifying the application using port 25 on my Windows-10 system. Any useful hints to list used ports and using applications without 3rd party applications ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without the use of any external software. Open a command prompt:

1. `netstat -abn`

OR

2. `netstat -a -n -p tcp -o`

Within **Task Manager** -> **Processes/Details** Tab

You can match the PID against the result of the second netstat command above, you can then find the image name/end the process etc if required.

There's also plenty of third party applications that can simplify the process and make the information easier to read, simple Google search if you want to find them.

Answer (score 16):

A GUI solution would be to use the `Resource Monitor` of Windows. You can start it by pressing `START` and entering this command: `Perfmon /Res`

Then you can click on the `Network` tab to view all network connections, listening ports, etc.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:
[image: Resource Monitor network tab]

Answer (score 4):

Open a command shell and run

```
netstat -a -n -p tcp -o
```

No need to run as administrator.

The last column is the PID. You can look up this PID in the task manager. Be sure to activate "show processes of all users" there.

See the [documentation for netstat](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961504.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

All of you were way behind. A far easier method (was, & still is in 2023) is first to open the Command Prompt.
(can do this by holding the windows logo key on your keybard+Cut&Paste, or just type in these 3 letters> cmd.
So, Winlogo+cmd)
Than type in or Copy(Ctrl+C), & Paste(Ctrl+V)
*To terminate running process:

cmd>TASKLIST

[choose the task you want to terminate,than:]

cmd>taskkill /IM [program name ie:]mswebview2.exe /F

*Typing help in cmd gives options after running something
too.  Sometimes, it may even provide an example,
that's how the above EASY method was obtained-
after very minimal tial & error.
So the very easy way after the tidbits above:

1. windowslogo+cmd
2. ```
               TASKLIST
   ```
3. ```
               taskkill /IM [program name ie:]mswebview2.exe /F
   ```

EASY METHOD + no "3rd.party" software .)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -n` from the command line will show you a list of IP addresses and open ports on your computer. A web search would probably be best in determining what is running on a particular port, but here's a few resources you could check open ports against:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml

EDIT: user544199's `netstat` arguments looks to put out some more useful information than mine. I would use that.

Answer (score 0):

The post requests responses without third party apps, however, others reading this may be more inclined toward a GUI.

For those looking for an application, TCPView seems to work best.

It is microsoft recommended and has a clear and easy to use GUI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Old now, but I use this powershell (saved as `simplens.ps1`):

```sh
$procs = Get-Process

$ports = netstat -ano
$ports[4..$ports.length] |
    # First column comes back empty, so we set to "ProcessName" as a placeholder for later
    ConvertFrom-String -PropertyNames ProcessName,Proto,Local,Remote,State,PID  | 
    where  State -eq 'LISTENING' | 
    foreach {
        $_.ProcessName = ($procs | where ID -eq $_.PID).ProcessName
        $_
    } | 
    Format-Table
```